# Azure Front Door unable to connect with wss/websync (websocket secure)

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-front-door

I've deployed .net application on Azure App service which works perfectly fine including webSync connections when I access it through custom domain or app service default domain, but only WebSync doesn't work when I enable the Azure Front Door and points my domain to go through Front Door to the backend app service.

My WebSync is running from a Azure VM and all the required ports are allowed, app service and VM are sharing the same VNET.

I am using Azure Front Door's "Standard" version, Do I need to switch to the premium version and connect with my app service through private link? but again my WebSync is running from a VM so it's not clear to me that why Azure Front Door is unable to connect with WebSync and all the other things are working fine.

I get following error (pic attached)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Front Door only supports HTTP, HTTPS and HTTP/2.

[image]
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-faq#what-protocols-does-azure-front-door-support-